# How to properly handle FirebaseAuth async results?

Tags: android, async-await, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

On my Android app I'm trying to implement a simple Sign In / Sign Up using FirebaseAuth. I'm wanted to use Kotlin Coroutines to properly handle the responses from Firebase.
So I added that to my gradle file:

```
"org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$kotlin_play_services_version"
```

After that, I was able to call `.await()` after a FirebaseAuth request.
So here's the code that's responsible for handling the Sign In:

```
override suspend fun signIn(email: String, password: String): JobResult<User> {

    var errorMessage = ""
    var user: User? = null

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            user = UserMapper().mapFromFirebaseUser(result.user)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { result ->
            errorMessage = result.message ?: CONSTANTS.BAD_REQUEST
            user = null
        }.await()

    user?.run {
        return JobResult.Success(this)
    }
    return JobResult.Fail(errorMessage, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)

}
```

So basically what's happening is that I'm calling Firebase's Sign In method passing the correct parameters, and adding a Success and a Failure Listener. Depending on the result, the variable `user` may contain the user's info or be null. And depending on that variable, I return a result of Success or Failure to the part of the code that requested it.

Everything works well if the result is positive (Success Listener), however, if the result is anything other than a successful result, the code after the `.await()` call is never executed! As if it is awaiting a successful result and will wait for it forever. It means that if the request fails for some reason, that suspend function will never return any results, it  just waits.

I want the rest of the code to run as soon as ANY result is received. How can I do it? Am I missing something obvious here?
Is there any way of "breaking out" of that `await()` and proceeding with the rest of the code once the Failure Listener is reached?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should write it like this instead.  If you're going to use coroutines, there's no need for attaching callback listeners to the Task.  Just await() the task and use try/catch to handle the results:

```
try {
    val result = firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
    val user = UserMapper().mapFromFirebaseUser(result.user)
    // continue using user here...
}
catch (e: Exception) {
    // deal with the error properly
}
```

Comment: I already tried like that, but the code doesn't continue the execution in case the signInWithEmailAndPassword() method fails. If I try to sign in with a user that does not exist, for example, await() function just keeps waiting forever.

Comment: Well, this is the correct format. The code should not wait forever. There is a timeout to the sign-in code, and if anything fails, it should end up in the catch block.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help! I just didn't want to rely on timeout, because if the user simply typed a wrong password, the failure result usually is immediate, there would be no need to wait for a timeout. I wanted to understand why the await() method is failing to recognize that the request is over :(

Comment: Hey Doug, just an update: I tried the code you suggested, it worked perfectly. Before I missed the try/catch block. Now if there's an error, the catch handles it as it should be. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
override suspend fun signIn(email: String, password: String): JobResult<User> = suspendCancellableCoroutine  { cont -> 

var errorMessage = ""
var user: User? = null

firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        user = UserMapper().mapFromFirebaseUser(result.user)
        if(cont.isActive){
           cont.resume(JobResult.Success(this))
        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { result ->
        errorMessage = result.message ?: CONSTANTS.BAD_REQUEST
        user = null
        if(cont.isActive){
            cont.resume(JobResult.Fail(errorMessage, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try this solution yet, but what exactly determines the value of this cont.isActive? What if it stays as True forever? I'll try it later and get back to you. Thanks! By the way, I believe your answer was downvoted due to lack of explanation, maybe you want to edit it :)

Comment: @RafsV. Did you try this solution? I am getting info that this solution is marked as experimental. This declaration is experimental and its usage should be marked with '@kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi' or '@OptIn(kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)'

Comment: ShadeToD I did not try this one, because the answer of Doug Stevenson helped me in the end. If you're having a similar problem, I suggest you try it out.